# Trouble with Custom Iterable in Batch Apex

Tags: apex, batch, iterable

I'm having some trouble implementing a Custom Iterable in Batch Apex. The goal is to update Accounts and Opportunties when information on the Owner's User Record has changed. Everything seemed correct as far as I can tell. The code executes, and I'm able to confirm that creating the Iterable does return the expected information, however, when I reach the execute() method, I find that the the List "objects" is empty, even though the iterable contains information. Am I missing something obvious. I have the relevant classes below:

Batch Class:

```
public class AccountRelatedUserUpdater implements Database.Batchable<sObject>, Database.Stateful {
    private final Map<Id, User> users;
    private final Map<Id, User> oldUsers;
    private final List<User_Sync_Mapping__mdt> mappings;
    private String errorCSV = 'Account Id, Error \n';
    private Boolean hasError = false;

    public AccountRelatedUserUpdater(Map<Id, User> users, Map<Id, User> oldUsers) {
        this.users = users;
        this.oldUsers = oldUsers;
        this.mappings = UserSyncMappingRepo.loadAll();
    }

    public Iterable<sObject> start(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
        Set<Id> ownerIds = users.keySet();

        return new RelatedUserObjectIterable(ownerIds);;
    }

    public void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List<SObject> objects) {
        List<SObject> objectsToUpdate = getObjectsToUpdate(objects);
        Database.saveResult[] results =  Database.update(objectsToUpdate, false);
        for (Database.SaveResult result : results) {
            if (!result.isSuccess()) {
                hasError = true;
                errorCSV += result.getId() + ', ' + result.getErrors() + '\n';
            }
        }
    }

    private List<SObject> getObjectsToUpdate(List<SObject> objects) {
        List<SObject> objectsToUpdate = new List<SObject>();
        for (SObject obj : objects) {
            if ('Account'.equals(obj.getSObjectType())) {
                obj = (Account) obj;
            }

            Id ownerId = (Id) obj.get('OwnerId');
            User newUser = users.get(ownerId);
            User oldUser = oldUsers.get(ownerId);

            for (User_Sync_Mapping__mdt mapping : mappings) {
                String userField = mapping.User_Field_Name__c;
                String destinationField = mapping.Destination_Object_Field_Name__c;

                if (oldUser != null && newUser.get(userField) != oldUser.get(userField) ||
                    oldUser == null && newUser.get(userField) != null)
                {
                    obj.put(destinationField, newUser.get(userField));
                }
            }

            objectsToUpdate.add(obj);
        }

        return objectsToUpdate;
    }

    public void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
    }
}
```

Iterator Class:

```
public class RelatedUserObjectIterator implements Iterator<SObject> {
    public List<SObject> objectsToCheck {get; set;}
    public Integer i {get; set;}

    public RelatedUserObjectIterator(Set<Id> userIds) {
        this.objectsToCheck = getObjectsToCheck(userIds);
        this.i = 0;
    }

    private List<SObject> getObjectsToCheck(Set<Id> userIds) {
        List<SObject> sObjects = new List<SObject>();
        sObjects.addAll([SELECT Id, OwnerId, Group_Manager__c FROM Account WHERE OwnerId IN :userIds]);
        sObjects.addAll([SELECT Id, OwnerId, Group_Manager__c FROM Opportunity WHERE OwnerId IN :userIds]);

        return sObjects;
    }

    public boolean hasNext() {
        return i >= objectsToCheck.size();
    }

    public SObject next() {
        if (i == objectsToCheck.size()) {
            return null;
        }
        i++;

        return objectsToCheck[i - 1];
    }
}
```

Iterable Class:

```
public class RelatedUserObjectIterable implements Iterable<SObject> {
    private final Set<Id> userIds;

    public RelatedUserObjectIterable(Set<Id> userIds) {
        this.userIds = userIds;
    }

    public Iterator<SObject> iterator() {
        return new RelatedUserObjectIterator(userIds);
    }
}
```

Comment: The iterator's hasNext logic looks wrong. Shouldn't this be saying there is a next when i < objectsToCheck.size()?

Comment: Please **[edit]** your post to include your code *here* if you wish for help from this community.

Comment: To add to @AdrianLarson's point - by using an external site you risk the code disappearing so future visitors finding this question and any answer will not have access to the detail of the code in question. Thereby making the question/answer valueless.

Comment: You're both right. I was trying to prevent the post from being cluttered, but you both make fair points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The iterator's hasNext logic needs to be changed to:

```
return i < objectsToCheck.size();
```

Comment: Well I feel dumb. That was it. I must still be suffering from vacation brain.